# Response.Redirect need to click twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, response.redirect

I have a input text box and the button when the button is pressed whatever is in the textbox should be appended as a querystring and be redirected to another url. However I need to click the button twice before the redirect happens.

This is the aspx code

```
<div class="userInputTextBox" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 10px;">
    <asp:TextBox
        placeholder="Enter costumer ID"
        ID="TextBoxID1"
        runat="server"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        Columns="80"
        Visible="true">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Search" />
</div>
```

Code behind with the Search method.

```
protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("UserDetail.aspx?UserID={0}", Server.HtmlEncode(TextBoxID1.Text)));

}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Note the URL should have `Server.URLEncode`, not `HtmlEncode`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured that I only needed to delete the `AutoPostBack="true"` property and it works ok now